# µTorrent auto remove completed download

Tags: automation, bittorrent, utorrent

I am using µTorrent v2. Is it possible to remove a file from µTorrent when a download has finished automatically? I want to keep µTorrent open rather then closing it down.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of just stopping at the point of completing a download, here are a few options (which I think uTorrent will also support) -- they are torrent friendly.

1. Limit upload rate
2. Stop seeding after a specific seeding ratio
   (like say 100%? or, 10% if you are not friendly).
3. Setup alternate upload rate when not downloading
   (meaning when you have probably completed all your downloads)

Comment: But the files remain in the list; how do you actually remove them?

Comment: You only tell what to do, but not show how to do it.  ....

Answer (score 8):

You can change the default behavior for the delete function:

Go to `Options -> Preferences -> Advanced`. Find the listing `gui.default_del_action`: change the value from `0` to `1`.

In fact, you can change the value from `0` all the way to `3` with the corresponding results:

`0` means "Remove" (remove the torrent job from the list, but all related files are left intact on the disk)

`1` means "Remove and delete .torrent" (remove the selected torrent job(s) from the list and the corresponding torrent file(s) from where the storage location on disk)

`2` means "Remove and delete Data" (remove the torrent selected job(s) from the list and all content downloaded from the torrent job(s))

`3` means "Remove and delete .torrent + Data" (remove the selected torrent job(s) from the list, the corresponding torrent file(s) from the storage location on disk, and all content downloaded from the torrent job(s))

Comment: do we need to restart it after setting it ?

Comment: why isn't this answer the ACCEPTED one!?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is.  I've written a script that accesses uTorrent's Web UI to remove completed torrents automatically.  You can find instructions on how to use it on my blog at:

http://www.aeonity.com/xuanming/automatically-remove-torrents-after-download

Comment: Perfect, event works with the trusty uTorrent 2.2.1.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes: click the finished torrent (it will be listed as *seeding*) and stop it (there's a `stop` button on the toolbar).
You can then delete or move the file.

You should be nice and seed the files you download so that others benefit from the file being distributed, too. that won't work if you stop the seeding and delete the file.

Comment: Some torrents have tens of thousands of seeds, so not everybody needs to keep seeding for days afterwards. Also, sometimes a torrent may download really slowly, so you end up uploading a lot while waiting for it finish. Do you insist that a person keep seeding after the file is done downloading even if they have already uploaded 2x as much while waiting for it finish?

Comment: @Bobson I don't insist on sharing at all. It's merely _recommended,_ not mandatory. If someone doesn't want to upload at all, I'm fine with that. And of course you're right that resharing starts as soon as soon as enough bits have been downloaded.

Comment: Fair enough; replace 'insist' with another word. The point is that everybody always says to seed after finishing, but I have seen plenty of cases where post-complete seeding is irrelevant.

Comment: Read the question. It says **auto remove**.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no built-in way to automatically remove a file in µTorrent. Automatically stopping it is the closest you can get.

Your best bet is to [request](http://forum.utorrent.com/viewforum.php?id=2) a way to automatically remove a torrent once it reaches the specified ratio, making sure to explain that you can already automatically stop torrents anyway, so automatically removing them is no more harmful than that.

Answer (score 1):

You should instead try **qBittorrent**, in [portableapps  format](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/qbittorrent_portable).

It has the feature to remove the torrent when it reaches your set ratio. I have mine set at 1,5 sometimes 2.0 as I am very friendly by nature.

Comment: This may be better as a comment to the original post

Answer (score 0):

Use the webAPI that utorrent provides. If you enable the webUI in utorrent you will be able to get to utorrent through your web browser. Checkout this webpage: http://www.utorrent.com/community/developers/webapi

Through the API you can send HTTP POST/GET requests to utorrent, which will enable you to remove a torrent when it's done.

In the utorrent options you can run a program when a torrent either changes state or has finished downloading. Use that feature together with the webAPI and create a simple script that does that for you.