# How to leave a download in Bittorrent's download list after completion

Tags: bittorrent

Recently when I woke up I found that my PC had shut itself down during the night, probably after a Windows update. I noticed some UI color changes, but also all my running downloads in Bittorrent had gone from its list. (The incomplete data was still there, and I could restore the downloads to their previous states after adding the .torrent files again.)

There were other small changes as well. For instance, after a download completes it is automagically deleted from the list, without any action by me. Previously I went to "Remove and" | "delete .torrent" in the context menu manually.

I would like to go back to this manual action. In [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/669194/453919) I found several options for deletion, but "don't delete" isn't one of them.

How can I leave downloads in the list after download completes?

Comment: "How can I leave downloads in the list after download completes?" - Don't delete the torrent.

Comment: @Ramhound: If you have read my question I think it should be clear that I don't delete them, they get deleted by themselves.

Comment: Right;  You have not determined the reason they deleted themselfs, what caused them to be deleted, cannot be determined based on the information you provided.  You shouldn't have to do anything, to prevent your client, from removing a completed torrent from your torrent list.  Your looking for special instructions when there isn't one.